# Counting Non-Negative Integer Solutions with Inequalities and Constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We want to calculate the number of non-negative integer solutions to the inequality A+B+C≤36, subject to the constraints A≤B≤C.

1. Transform the above inequality, subject to constraints, into an equivalent equation without restrictions regarding the number of non-negative integer solutions. Hint: An inequality X≤Y between terms X and Y that takes non-negative integer values is equivalent (in terms of non-negative integer solutions) to the equation X+Z=Y, where the new variable Z also takes non-negative integer values. Use this equivalence, along with appropriate auxiliary variables, to first eliminate the value constraints on the variables and then convert the inequality into an equation
2. Formulate the generating function that encodes the number of non-negative integer solutions to the equation found in 1, along with the appropriate coefficient that provides the desired count. By performing suitable algebraic operations, show that the generating function you found is equal to $$F(x) = \frac{1}{(1 - x^3)(1 - x^2)} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}$$
   Hint: Utilize the following identity, which pertains to an infinite series of geometric progression terms with a ratio

$$0<\lambda<1: \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda^k=\frac{1}{1-\lambda}.$$

Let's start by converting the inequality

A+B+C≤36 under the constraints into an equivalent equation without constraints. As suggested, we can use the inequality X≤Y as the equation X+Z=Y, where the new variable Z also takes non-negative integer values.

To convert the inequality, we can set

X=A,

Y=A+B+C, and introduce

$Z_1 $
​
and
$Z_2 $
​
such that
$Z_1≥0 $ and
$Z_2≥0 $
​
This results in the equations:

\begin{align*}
X &= A \newline
Y &= A + B + C \newline
Z_1 &\geq 0 \newline
Z_2 &\geq 0
\end{align*}

We then rewrite the inequality as:

$$X + Z_1 + Z_2 = Y$$

Solution 2:

To find the generating function for the number of solutions, let's express each of the variables in terms of generating functions. We have:

\begin{align*}
X &\text{ represented by } x \newline
Y &\text{ represented by } \frac{1}{1 - x} \quad \text{(as it's a geometric series)} \newline
Z_1 &\text{ represented by } \frac{1}{1 - x} \quad \text{(using the identity for a geometric series)} \newline
Z_2 &\text{ represented by } \frac{1}{1 - x} \quad \text{(same as } Z_1)
\end{align*}

Now, we can write the equation in generating function form:

$$x\cdot\frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} = \frac{x}{(1 - x)^4}$$

This generating function represents the count of non-negative integer solutions to the equation

$X+Z_1+Z_2 =Y.$

By simplifying this expression further, we get:

$$\frac{1}{(1 - x^3)(1 - x^2)} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}$$

What do you guys think? Is my approach right?

Comment: You can’t just say “by simplifying this expression further we get…” without doing the actual simplifications. Those two expressions are not equal; you just claimed they were equal so the work you did would match the answer. Look, it’s OK to be stuck and confused, just be honest about your actual progress.

Answer (score 1):

We want to count solutions to the system
$$
\begin{cases}
A + B + C = 36,\\
A \ge B\\
B \ge C\\
C \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$
The fundamental tool we will use is the this: solutions to a system with the constraint $S\ge T$ are equivalent to solutions to the same system but where $S$ is replaced with $T+R$ everywhere, and were we required the new variable $R\ge 0$.

For example, in the above equation, we have $A\ge B$. We introduce a new variable, $D$, and substitute $A = B + D$ everywhere for $B$ in the system. The result is
$$
\begin{cases}
(B + D) + B + C = 36,\\
\color{gray}{B + D \ge B}\\
B \ge C\\
C \ge 0\\
D \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$
Note that the inequality $B+D\ge B$ is redundant, as it is implied by $D\ge 0$. This means we can delete it. The only problematic inequality remaining is $B\ge C$. Using the same trick to remove that, we let $B=E + C$, and substitute that everywhere for $B$. The result is
$$
\begin{cases}
((C + E + D) + (C + E) + C = 36,\\
C \ge 0,
D \ge 0,
E \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\begin{cases}
3C+2E+D = 36,\\
C \ge 0,
D \ge 0,
E \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$
You can now solve this with generating functions. The monomial $D$ can contribute any nonnegative integer to the total, so the generating function for $E$ is $$1x^0+1x^1+1x^2+\dots=\frac1{1-x}.$$ The monomial $2E$ can contribute any nonnegative **even** amount, so the g.f. for $2E$ is $$1x^0+\color{gray}{0x^1}+1x^2+\color{gray}{0x^3}+1x^4+\dots=\frac1{1-x^2}.$$ Similarly, the g.f. for $3C$ is $\frac1{1-x^3}.$ Multiplying these altogether, we get the desired answer.

Comment: if we multiply your result we get $\frac{1}{{(1-x^2)}} \cdot \frac{1}{{(1-x^3)}} \cdot \frac{1}{{(1-x)}}$ but we want:
 $\frac{1}{{(1-x^2)}} \cdot \frac{1}{{(1-x^3)}} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{{(1-x)}}\right)^2$

Comment: The given answer is wrong, and my answer is correct.